# echo json_encode($data,TRUE) is not going back to the ajax function in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-2, json

My code is

```
<script>
 $("#saveExpense").click(function(){
     alert('I am in jquery function');
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET', 
        url: "<?php echo site_url('expenses/addExpense');?>",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:$('#AddExpenseForm').serialize(), 
        success: function(response) {
            comsole.log(response);
            var curlen = response.length;

            var htm = curlen+"| &nbsp;"+response[curlen-1].Category+"| &nbsp;"+response[curlen-1].Amount+"| &nbsp;"+response[curlen-1].Comments+"| &nbsp;Edit/Delete<br />";

             $("#ShowExpenses").append(htm); 
        }
    });
 });
```

My controller is

```
function addExpense(){
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        redirect('expenses','refresh');
    $this->expenses_model->addExpense();
    $data=$this->expenses_model->viewExpenses();
    echo json_encode($data,TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Well for one, you spelled `console` wrong in your success callback. Two, check your console for any specific errors, or what the response is (like if it was a 301 redirect or 404 not found).

Comment: Cryode, I found the solution.